# C# - Can't seem to figure out how to open 2 forms from program.cs and connect with the sqlite database

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, sqlite

So, I've written an import/export function on my application, and I have set a file extension associated with my application. When exporting reminders, it creates a .remindme file. This can be opened, and it is caught in my program.cs like this

```
        [STAThread]
        [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {                       
            using (Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, "Global\\" + "RemindMe"))
            {
                if (!mutex.WaitOne(0, false))
                {
                    if (args.Length > 0)
                    {//The user double-clicked an .remindme file while remindme is running!   

                        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                        Application.Run(new Import(args[0]));
                    }
                    //one instance of remindme already running                                        
                    return;
                }

                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.ThreadException += new System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);                
                Application.Run(new Form1());
            }    
        }
```

I tried making an new instance of Import(a windows-form) here, and doing `Import.Show()` , but that doesn't work. I've searched all over the place, and the only thing I found is by using `Application.Run()` on the form. This does indeed launch it, but it creates another instance of my application. This carries problems with it, including not being able to use the database.

When I double-click the .remindme file while the application is running, using a second `Application.Run()` the form successfully launches.

[image]

But, when I press yes(attempts to insert data into the database) it throws an EntityException

[image]

[full stacktrace on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/xE0SbK1Z)

After some digging I found that I can't use two instances using the same SQLite database. This new form counts as a new instance, because I used `Application.Run`

**So, in conclusion** what I'm looking for is a way to launch a new form from program.cs (because that's where I catch the double-click on a .remindme file)

Comment: What ? :) I've read you post and for me, it is something like this: "I've bought a new shirt, the game was great, my girlfriend is ugly, and i don't' know how to draw this painting. So my question is: "how can I be taller by 10 cm"

Comment: is it really that bad? well i'll try to ask it in one line

"How can i start a new windows-form when the main windows-form is already up, **from program.cs** ? note: `Application.Run()` doesn't seem to be an option though"

Comment: I'm not a guru in winforms. I don't have business experience. I have a little bit more experience with WPF (and MVVM) but still, it is hoppy experience (not the bussines one) If it was about WPF (and MVVM and caliburn.micro as a framework) I would suggest changing the screen to new screen and that would be it. Maybe you should discover new technologies (Winforms are somehow obsolete)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching, i came to a solution of sending a windows process message, and it works well!

I got it working using the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777668/send-message-to-a-windows-process-not-its-main-window)